# Выборка с матрицы в MatLab

Tags: matlab

Мне нужно выбрать с базы рандомно 20% значений(строчек) по классу "1", их перенести в другую матрицу, а с прошлой удалить..но у меня что-то получается только сохранить и удалить одно значения...вот база [здесь](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00267/data_banknote_authentication.txt)

```
M = load('base.txt');
class = 1;
set = find(M(:,5)==class);
lengClass = length(set);
per = round(lengClass*0.2);

r = randi([set(1,:), set(lengClass,:)],1,per);

for i=1:610
    for j=1:per
        if set(i,:) == r(1:j)
            Mt(j,:) = M(set(i,:),:);
            M(set(i,:),:)=[];
        end
    end    
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M = load('base.txt'); % підключення бази
Mt = []; % сворення пустої матриція для тестових значень
k = 1; % індекс для заповнення тестової матриці
columnNumberClass = 5; % номер стовпця, де знаходить значення класу
for class=0:1 % цикл для проходження всіх класів
    selectClass = find(M(:,columnNumberClass)==class); % вибираємо значення стрічок певного класу
    lengClass = length(selectClass); % кількість стрічок 
    per = round(lengClass*0.2); % підраховуєм скільки значень потрібно для тествої вибріки, в даном випадку 20%
    r = randi([selectClass(1,:),selectClass(lengClass,:)],1,per); % генеруємо рандомні значення
    for i=1:lengClass %проходимо матрицю з бази
        for j=1:per %проходимо рандомні значення
            if selectClass(i) == r(1) % якщо рандомне значення співпадає з номером рядку то 
                Mt(k,:) = M(selectClass(i),:); % додаємо його то тестової матриці
                M(selectClass(i,:),:)=[];% видаляємо його з основної матриці
                k = k +1;% додаємо до індекса для заповнення тестової матриці
            end
        end    
    end  
end
```